# Solving race condition using SemaphoreSlim

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, race-condition

> A race condition occurs when two threads access a shared variable at the same time. The first thread reads the variable, and the second thread reads the same value from the variable.

I used `SemaphoreSlim` in `StartAsync` to prevent a race condition, i.e. two threads may change `_clientWebSocket` concurrently. It may happen if we're calling StartAsync in a `Timer`.

What about `StopAsync`? If StopAsync wasn't wrapped in a SemaphoreSlim, what are the chances two threads to pass through the `if` condition and call CloseOutputAsync twice? The first one would close the output successfully, but the second call would fail with WebSocketException because the web socket is already closed. Is that a race condition too taking into account that we aren't changing any variables? Is it going to happen at all and do I really need the try/catch that wraps the CloseOutputAsync, taking into account that no other part of my code closes the web socket?

I reused that SemaphoreSlim in StopAsync in order to prevent calling StartAsync and StopAsync at the same time, is that a good idea?

```cs
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new(1, 1);

public async Task StartAsync(string url)
{
    await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    try
    {
        var ws = new ClientWebSocket();
        _clientWebSocket = ws;

        await _clientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(url), CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false); // TODO: Handle

        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        _ = ReceiveLoopAsync(ws, _tokenSource.Token);
        _ = SendLoopAsync(ws);
    }
    finally
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}

public async Task StopAsync()
{
    await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    try
    {
        if (_clientWebSocket is { State: not (WebSocketState.Aborted or WebSocketState.Closed or WebSocketState.CloseSent) })
        {
            try
            {
                await _clientWebSocket.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception) // thrown when we try to close an already closed socket
            {
            }
        }

        _clientWebSocket?.Dispose();
        _clientWebSocket = null;

        _tokenSource?.Cancel();
    }
    finally
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be more worried about calling `ReceiveLoopAsync` and `SendLoopAsync`. I assume both are returning tasks, so you presumably have no idea if they fail. And you do not seem to be doing any synchronization between these methods and the disposing of the websocket. I would have expected the stop method to first cancel the loops, wait for them to actually complete any remaining work, and *then* dispose the socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that if you expect `StopAsync` being called in parallel then it's worth having those measures around.

Though there is another potential flaw that I see in your code -  you are sharing `_clientWebSocket` and `_tokenSource` between the start and stop so potentially you can end in next situation:

1. *Thread 1* calls `StartAsync` and initializes `_clientWebSocket` and `_tokenSource` and exists the semaphore
2. *Thread 2* calls `StartAsync` and overwrites `_clientWebSocket` and `_tokenSource`
3. *Thread 1* `StopAsync` calls `StopAsync` which will stop `ClientWebSocket` created by *Thread 2* but no one will close the one created by *Thread 1*

Comment: Fair point. In that case, I don't really need the SemaphoreSlim in StopAsync, I would just leave the try/catch and have some checks in StartAsync whether the web socket client is already running or not

Comment: @nop that is not the point. `SemaphoreSlim` or not it won't prevent the potential override of `_clientWebSocket`.

Comment: @nop as for the original question - personally I would prefer the semaphore approach rather than catching/handling exceptions. Also there possible are other exceptions which you will currently swallow - not sure that you want to.